# Frequent baby name based on year and gender

Tags: python, pandas

I was given a Baby dataset consist of three columns: `'Gender','Name','Year'.` I have to construct a code in order to find the most frequent baby name in year 1910 based on gender 'M' but I couldn't think of correct syntax to do it, here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("C:\\users\\USER\\Documents\\Dataset_file\\baby_names.csv")

frequent = data[data['Sex' == 'M'][data['Year'] == 1910]]['Name'].value_counts()[0:1]
frequent
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) with selection values in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), both mask chain by `&` for bitwise AND:

```
frequent = data.loc[(data['Sex' == 'M') & (data['Year'] == 1910), 'Name'].mode().iat[0]
```

Your solution is possible change for get first value of index:

```
frequent = data.loc[(data['Sex' == 'M') & (data['Year'] == 1910), 
                    'Name'].value_counts().index[0]
```